# Как найти вхождение заданного элемента в отсортированном векторе?

Tags: c++

Как найти вхождение заданного элемента в отсортированном векторе, если число может повторяться любое количество раз?

```
sort(result.begin(), result.end()); 
do 

{
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)

        {
            double x = (a + b) / 2;
            if (dix < x)
            {
                b = x;
                    
            }
            else
            {
                a = x;
            }
        }
    } while ((a - b) > dix);
```

}

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Comment: надо вывести их индексы, а не последнего вхождения

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range

Comment: также см. lower_bound и upper_bound